# Trying to use a sentinel controlled loop to add and average a bunch of integers

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, sentinel

I want to add a bunch of numbers together, with the final number being the sentinel (`999`). If `999` is typed, then the input loop ends and the answers are printed, otherwise it keeps looping and adding input. But when I run the program, it shows the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lab9.py", line 4, in <module>
    sum += kbInput
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'
```

Code is below:

```
kbInput = input()
while int(kbInput) != 999:
        kbInput = input()
        sum += kbInput
        count += 1
        average = sum/average
print("Sum", sum)
print("Average", average)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sum` is built-in function. Use the name `sum_` and set it to zero before the loop:

```
sum_ = 0
count = 0
while True:
    kbInput = float(input())
    if kbInput == 999:
        break
    sum_ += kbInput
    count += 1
average = sum_ / count
print("Sum", sum_)
print("Average", average)
```